# Stop Edge browser trying to select words across elements

Tags: javascript, css, selection, microsoft-edge

The current Edge browser tries to select entire words of text across different elements. If moving the mouse fast enough, it'll snap to entire words.

The effect is demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/n7t43ac7/1/ (use Edge browser to see it).

Chrome does not do this; it doesn't try to snap to words.
In my particular use case, I prefer if Edge behaved like Chrome.

Is it possible to control this behavior in Edge from CSS or JavaScript? `-ms-user-select` doesn't seem to help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look across 1st party Windows Applications this behaviour is the same. Word for example exhibits the same behaviour. As you drag selection in one direction it will snap to each word. If you keep the mouse held down after you pass the boundary of a word and move in the opposite direction you then get more granular control of the letter selection.

Since this behaviour is present in multiple applications it would appear that it's by design inside of Edge.

There is no way to control this behaviour as a developer in Edge through CSS properties. My only suggestion would be to raise it as a suggestion on the Edge Uservoice.

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/